# For $H=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}:3x+4y\equiv 0 \mod 5\}$, find a group isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^2\to H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working through group theory problems and I'm trying to do the following exercise:

> For $H=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}:3x+4y\equiv 0 \mod 5\}$, find a group isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^2\to H$ and show $[\mathbb{Z}^2:H]=5.$

I tried defining the group isomorphism in $5$ cases, letting the value of $f(x,y)\in H\subset\mathbb{Z}^2$ depend on the value of $y$ modolu $5$, but it didn't work out since the map wasn't even a homomorphism. Also, it is really simple to find an injective homomorpism by $(x,y)\mapsto(5x,5y)$, but that does not really help either, of course. I thought about choosing a map that fixes the second element, and by using an enumeration of all solutions of $3x+4y\equiv 0 \mod 5$ for each value of $y$, mapping $k\geq0$ to the $(k+1)$'th positive solution for $x$ and similarly for $k<0$. However, this also does not seem to give rise to a homomorphism, although it seems (to me) a well-defined bijection.

I think I'm missing some clever trick I can use but I don't see it. Can anyone give me a hint for the homomorphism? I think after that the second part (showing that $[\mathbb{Z}^2:H]=5$ is not too difficult therafter), so my question is mainly about the first part. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Find the generators of $H$.

Comment: I'm not sure you meant "isomorphism" but, in fact, *homomorphism*...didn't you?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks for your hint! I did the following now, is this what you intended with your hint? I showed $(1,3),(2,1)$ are two linearly independent solutions and that $H$ is a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}$, so by linear independency I inferred that $H=\langle(1,3),(2,1)\rangle$. Than by writing each element in $H$ as a linear combination with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ of these two vectors, I chose $f:\mathbb{Z}^2\to H:(x,y)\mapsto x(1,3)+y(2,1)$. Is this right?

Comment: @DonAntonio: The question in my syllabus says (group) "isomorphism". Might be a typo by the writer of course, but what I did following Michael Burr's hint seems to yield a isomorphism, right?

Comment: For the index is $5$ part, observe that $H$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/5$ by $(x,y)\mapsto (3x+4y)\mod 5$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr thank you very much for your help. I did that part by showing that there are exactly $5$ left cosets, i.e. $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:3x+4y\equiv k\mod 5\}$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4$. Your way is even quicker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas for you:

Define, for example,

$$f(1,0):=(2,1)\;,\;\;f(0,1):=(3,-1)$$

and extend the definition to $\;\Bbb Z^2\;$ by $\;\Bbb Z\,-$ linearity ( which is simply to apply the universal property of the free abelian group $\;\Bbb Z^2\;$ on the free generators $\;(1,0),\,(0,1)\;$). Observe that you get for free that $\;f\;$ is a group homomorphism. Now just show it is onto and its kernel has actually index $\;5\;$.

Comment: Thank you. I came this far using Michael Burr's comment, and I will now try to show the index equals $5$

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov Very nice. Observe that as you wrote it, it could be infered that $\;\Bbb Z^2\cong H\;$ , whereas the truth is that $\;H\;$ is isomorphis with a *quotient* group of $\;\Bbb Z^2\;$ ...

Comment: So I made a mistake somewhere in my proof? I thought that this quotient group should also be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$, just like $5\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$?